# Dynamic parent/child in a table

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I make `parent("td").prevAll("td")` to be dynamic?

```
$("body").on("click",".edit-item",function(){
    var id = $(this).parent("td").data('id');
    var name = $(this).parent("td").prevAll("td").eq(9).text();
    var email = $(this).parent("td").prevAll("td").eq(8).text();
    var phone = $(this).parent("td").prevAll("td").eq(7).text();
    var CNP = $(this).parent("td").prevAll("td").eq(6).text();
    var birthday = $(this).parent("td").prevAll("td").eq(5).text();
    var date = $(this).parent("td").prevAll("td").eq(4).text();
    var speciality_id = $(this).parent("td").prevAll("td").eq(3).text();
    var doctor_id = $(this).parent("td").prevAll("td").eq(2).text();
    var location_id = $(this).parent("td").prevAll("td").eq(1).text();
    var message = $(this).parent("td").prevAll("td").eq(0).text();

    $("#edit-item").find("input[name='name']").val(name);
    $("#edit-item").find("input[name='email']").val(email);
    $("#edit-item").find("input[name='phone']").val(phone);
    $("#edit-item").find("input[name='CNP']").val(CNP);
    $("#edit-item").find("input[name='birthday']").val(birthday);
    $("#edit-item").find("input[name='date']").val(date);
    $("#edit-item").find("select[name='speciality_id']").val(speciality_id);
    $("#edit-item").find("select[name='doctor_id']").val(doctor_id);
    $("#edit-item").find("select[name='location_id']").val(location_id);
    $("#edit-item").find("textarea[name='message']").val(message);
    $("#edit-item").find("form").attr("action",url + '/' + id);
});
```

Comment: `How can I make parent("td").prevAll("td") to be dynamic?` It's not clear what you mean. It may help if you showed us the associated HTML and made it clear which element you want to select

Comment: I just want to make a clear code, without so many lines and so on. I'm still in school and I was told to get information on that and to do this code like that. Less lines that do the same thing so I won't have to add another line each time I add another object in table.

Comment: so you got a task at school and want SO users to do your job?

Comment: Like I said, I've been told to get information on that and to do that. I've searched everywhere I could and I didn't find what I need so I asked here. I don't ask anyone to do it for me just to explain it and to give an example.

Comment: Well you're setting each value, so you need to create that many selectors, however you can certainly improve the code by storing `$('#edit-item')` and `$(this).parent("td").prevAll("td")` in variables.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for your time.